# How to do time tracing for *monolithic* clearly-moduled systems (not distributed systems), or should we do that?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I see many distributed tracing solutions for microservices. For instance, Spring Cloud Sleuth, Zipkin’s Brave, etc. However, I have a *monolithic* service with many modules separated clearly. Thus, those solutions do not work for me.

IMHO I need a tracing system to tell me which *module* (analogy to which *microservice* in a non-monolithic system) spends how much time. However, I could not find any. Thus, I wonder whether my need is actually *not* a real need but a pseudo need? Or, if it is a real need, how can I find some solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: *You* decide whether it's a real need. Do you have some reason to believe the information is useful? If so, insert tracing at the appropriate places. However, you might consider just using _metrics_ if you think you have particular hot spots; Boot can handle this for you automatically with Micrometer `@Timed`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thanks very much! My naive thought was: I was choosing monolithic instead of microservice, but to make the code clean (as clean as microservice), I make it very organized into modules. Thus, my monolithic is a "pseudo-microservice" to some extent. So I want to have that microservice monitoring :) I will try to use Timed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably uncommon to use sleuth for this kind of use-case (sleuth is mainly used to achieve distributed tracing and monitor critical latencies inside a system).

But...Sleuth integrates with logging frameworks like Logback and SLF4J to add unique identifiers that help track and diagnose issues using logs.

So when a request enters into your system sleuth will assign it a `TraceId` and all the various steps in that request, even across application and thread boundaries, will have the same `traceId`.

If you want to monitor different complex actions taken inside some module you can wrap these actions with a a dedicated `Span`.

Example :

```java
   Span newSpan = tracer.nextSpan().name("module1Span").start();
   try (SpanInScope ws = tracer.withSpanInScope(newSpan.start())) {
       // Some logic
   } finally {
       newSpan.finish();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the "traceid", and it sounds interesting! By the way, if only using the traceid, is there any more lightweighted solutions?